# Converting object returned by MongoDB into bar?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I think this is a very simple question? I am a beginner trying to learn mongo with node.

Once I have saved something to a collection, how can I pull it out in simple var format?

```
db.highschools.save({ 
            hsid    :10,
            name    :"Johnson High School",
            location:"San Diego, CA"
});
```

I simply want to store a var as 'Johnson High School'.

My failed attempts that have returned undefined are as follows...

```
var hsName = db.highschools.find({hsid:10}).name;

var hsName = db.highschools.find({hsid:10}).name.str;
```

Pretty sure I'm missing the big picture here, would someone please be kind enough to help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `findOne` instead:

```
var hsName = db.highschools.findOne({hsid:10}).name;
```

Also, note that this is a Mongo script, not a NodeJS script.

Comment: I think that downvoter wanted you to explain why you chose findOne. Here is the javascript behind the `findOne` function: http://codebin.org/view/9746f5da

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make it async when you write the logic in NodeJS.

```
db.collection('students', function(err, collection) {
    collection.findOne({hsid:10}, function(err, student) {
        if (err) { throw err; } 
        console.log(student.name);
    });
});
```

If you're confident that there should be only one result, then you can use the shortcut method `findOne` which simply calls `find` internally with a `limit` of one. If you were to use `find`, it returns an array of matches.

Comment: Don't forget that the OP asked for a Mongo script that is run with `mongo scriptname.js`. I suppose you downvoted me.. but it would be good to leave a comment. :-)

Comment: Never assume you understand the mind of a downvoter. Regardless, I don't see mention of `mongo scriptname.js` in the question? It was tagged with Node.JS. You provided an answer that wasn't related to Node.JS.

Comment: If the question has a wrong tag, should the answers be downvoted? Retaging would be better. It's clear that OP asked about a Mongo script because of the syntax. `findOne` in Mongo scripts is sync. I retaged the question.

Comment: The OP asked, "beginner trying to learn mongo with node". So, it was tagged correctly.